# How can we find Color is empty in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have a `Color` property in my custom class.. How can we find that Color is Empty in Silverlight ? . In Wpf, we have property `IsEmpty`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Color` object has default value of `#00000000`.
You can check from its A,R,G,B values. All of these are 0.

Following possibilities:

```
Color cl = new Color();//here A,R,G,B all are 0
```

Then:

```
Color cl;//same case
if(cl.A==0 && cl.R==0 && cl.G==0 && cl.B==0)
{
  //do work here
}
```

Then:

```
Color cl = Colors.Transparent;//This one is easier for comparison like in following condition
if(cl == Colors.Transparent)
{
  //do work here
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt that we can use Colors.Transparent also to check IfEmpty means.. Why we have two different properties Transparent, IsEmpty in WPF?. .. Then there might be difference right.... i want to know that difference..

Comment: I have mentioned `Colors.Transparent` as a workaround.
There is no property like `IsEmpty` so we can check in condition whether `Colors.Transparent` matches with the Color object.

Comment: What is the ARGB values for Colors.Transparent ?

Comment: Thanks vaibhav... Now i got cleared that... We can find When Color.IsEmpty in SL.. That means... When we have A=0,R=0,G=0,B=0... at that time Color will be empty...